# how to show 20 rows on datagrid each time?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i show data on gridview like this:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM MEN ";
                    dsView = new DataSet();
                    adp = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, Conn);
                    adp.Fill(dsView, "MEN");
                    adp.Dispose();
                    GridView1.DataSource = dsView.Tables["MEN"];
                    GridView1.DataBind();
```

but i see along list...

how to show Every time only 10 rows ?

i work on asp.net and C#

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use a paged datagrid. Its a better practice.

EDIT :  `<asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" AllowPaging="True" />`

After allowing paging to datagrid, you'l need to do something like this..

```
private void DataGrid1_PageIndexChanged(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid1.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    DataGrid1.DataBind();
}
```

See an an example for datagrids, [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anjudidi/308062009080934am/3.aspx).

Comment: i got this error: Error 5 The name 'DataGrid1' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @gold: thats correct. Datagrid1 is just a sample name. You have to replace that with whatever is your datagrid's id.

Comment: i work with GridView and your sample dont work. when i get into PageIndexChanged i got this:  protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `LIMIT 10` to only show 10 rows.
`LIMIT 30, 10` will show 10 rows, starting at row 30.

Comment: It's part of the SQL query, at the end. However, that's a pretty low-level approach. Pagination (as outlined in the other answers) is probably a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

1)
Also you can achieve this by using Stored Procedure, Please see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/row_number.aspx) for more. RowNumber does the magic in SQL Server, I am not sure about Oracle or other DB whether RowNumber exist in that.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getzipcodes] 

     @start int = 0
 AS
 BEGIN
 Set NOCOUNT ON
 SELECT TOP 20 * FROM 
 (
      SELECT zip,city,state,latitude,longitude,timezone,dst,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY zip) AS num
      FROM dbo.zipcode
 ) AS a
 WHERE num > @start
END
```

2)

You can use Pagination, Just need to set following attributes at grid tags,

```
  AllowPaging="True" and PageSize="25".
```

AllowPaging: setting for Pagination.
PageSize : Displaying number of records on the page.

Comment: The question is "How?" Please expand this answer to include information on "how" to make pagination help in this scenario.

Comment: Ohh, My apology, Modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did a blog post on Custom Paging and Sorting for the Telerik RadGrid. The concepts are still valid for an ASP GridView.

http://dotnetblogger.com/post/2010/03/07/RadGrid-with-Custom-Paging-Sorting-Filtering.aspx

Basically you want to add pagination to your grid and you probably don't want to return everything "*" from your database.

Pagination will increase DB performance and site speed dramatically.  Trust me.